# Wide-angle camera of Samsung Galaxy M21 not detectable by 3rd-party apps

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-m21

I have bought a Samsung Galaxy M21 smartphone which has got 3 cameras-- 2 rear cameras (48MP primary camera + 8MP wide-angle camera) and a front camera. The stock camera app works well, but for some more features, I have installed a few 3rd-party apps from the Play store. But, the problem is, those 3rd-party cameras are giving access to only the primary rear camera and the front camera, but not giving access to the wide-angle camera.
Those apps are able to detect the presence of 3 cameras, but two of the camera options are referencing to the same front camera.
Here is the example with **Open camera**:
[image]
I have tried all the controls and settings, but it gives access to only the primary rear camera and the front camera.

Is this behaviour normal? If so, what are the workarounds?

Comment: Sounds to me linke this OpenCamera bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/tickets/724/

Comment: Thanks for the link, that was indeed the problem I am facing.